# Map users to a group using an id where the group description contain the id

Tags: mysql, sql

What I am trying to achieve is:

1. Get the user group id from (tableB.value)
2. Map (tableB.value) to the (tableA.description) in the group.
3. Then list the (tableA.slug) for all those records that match.

I have two tables.
Table a contains the group description and slug. The description can be like "Hello I am 1" or "Hello I am 1,3" or "1"
Table b contains the user group id's Each user can have multiple group id's represented in the column value like "1,22,3"

I have been going around and around, the query below only seems to work for a one-to-one find. Where Table a matches exactly table b, I also have tried different like options but I keep crashing.

```
    SELECT
    a.description, 
    b.`value`,
    a.slug
FROM
    tableA as a
    INNER JOIN
    tableB as b
    ON 
        FIND_IN_SET(a.`description`, b.`value`)
```

Table structures added upon request (sorry should have done the first)
TableA

| id | slug | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | slug-1 | Hello I am 1 |
| 2 | slug-2 | Hello I am 5,3 |
| 3 | slug-3 | Hello I am 4,22 |

TableB

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 22,3 |
| 3 | 3,1 |

Expected outcome TableC

| id | value | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | slug -1 |
| 2 | 22 | slug-3 |
| 3 | 3 | slug-2 |

Comment: Please provide the tables as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts - this allow to reproduce your task.

Comment: *The description can be like "Hello I am 1" or "Hello I am 1,3" or "1"* - you must remove all symbols except ones which specifies the codes. If the only prefix to be removed may be `'Hello I am '` then use TRIM() else use REGEXP_REPLACE(). To check the interference of two CSV lists use JSON_OVERLAPS().

Comment: The list for row 1 in table A ("Hello I am 1") intersects with both row 1 ("1") and row 3 ("3,1") in table B. Why second interference is absent in the desired output?

Comment: "Why second interference is absent in the desired output?"
Because a reference is already in the table.